# Accessing the array of number from the file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have pred_data.txt as

> 19.08541,17.41787,16.59118,16.03507,15.68560
>
> 20.01880,18.21,19.48975,19.32,19.29945
>
> 17.32453,17.434,15.4253,12.422,11.4311

```
f=open('pred_data.txt','r')
for value in f:
    exam=np.array(value)
    pred=clf.predict(exam)
    print(pred)
```

When I run this, I got

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:'19.08541,17.41787,16.59118,16.03507,15.68560\n'

But when I try like this:`example=np.array([19.08541,17.41787,16.59118,16.03507,15.68560])
                      pred=clf.predict(example)`

I got the predicted output. How to access the data from the file to get output?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the function "fromstring" from numpy.
I think in your case it should be something like:

```
f = open("pred_data.txt", 'r').read()
preds = np.fromstring(f,  sep=",")
print(preds)
```

It's might not be the best way, but it's work.

See:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but wouln't it help to split the line/value into an array beforehand?
I mean

```
for value in f:
    exam=np.array(value.split(','))
    ...
```

This way it would be easier to convert a list if strings into a list of floats instead of converting a full line of floats as strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a line from the file, it comes out as a str. So in your example this:

```
for value in f:
    np.array(value)
```

Is the same as this:

```
np.array('19.08541,17.41787,16.59118,16.03507,15.68560\n')
```

You need to get rid of the `\n` with strip and break this into actual units using split:

```
values_strs = value.strip().split(',')
```

But that will leave you will a list of strs. It's better to cast those as well using `float`:

```
# This is a comprehension. It's a bit clearer and more obvious than
# calling `map(float, value.strip().split(','))`, but they boil down
# to a similar idea.
values_flt = [float(v) for v in value.strip().split(',')]
```

Altogether, you could just simplify to:

```
exam = np.array(float(v) for v in value.strip().split(','))
```

Comment: When I used `exam = np.array(float(v) for v in value.strip().split(','))`                I got like this <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000266DAF54410> in `print(exam)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy's loadtxt function.

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.loadtxt('pre_data.txt', delimiter=',')
```